# MicroStrategy ApplySimple Syntax

Tags: syntax, microstrategy

i'm trying to use the *ApplySimple* function in order to define a Metric in MicroStratey. My gloal is to cast a fact column to double value.

My current metric definition is:

```
ApplySimple("TO_DOUBLE(#0)", MYFACT)
```

The syntax check reports a wrong expression and indicates the error by marking the comma.

I tried to remove the MYFACT parameter including comma, but the syntax check fails as well, indicating the error on right parenthesis.

```
ApplySimple("TO_DOUBLE(MYFACT)")
```

Any suggentions on how to correct the syntax?

Thank you very much!

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just got the problem. You have to use ";" insted of "," after the expression.

Comment: Then mark your answer as the correct one. Probably your region settings want you to use `;` as separator.